# How to animate button view in the end of scrolling webview content?

Tags: swift, webview, uikit, jquery-animate

I'm trying to find how to animate the button view after the scrolling end, so it's not that snappy.

How to do that? (i want to upload the video buat i don't know how)

so here's the screenshots

[image][image]

Here's my code:

```
extension TabMenu: UIScrollViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if isUrlLoaded {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            
            self.webView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.bottom.equalTo(self.buttonView.snp.top)
            }
            self.buttonView.isHidden = false
            
        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.contentSize.height {
            
            webView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
                make.bottom.equalTo(scrollViewContainer.snp.bottom)
            }
            buttonView.isHidden = true
            
        }
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    isUrlLoaded = true
}
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: upload video at https://streamable.com/ and share link...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your constraint changes inside a UIView.animate block with a short duration (try 0.2 seconds as a starting point.) (or rather, put your call to `layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block, since that's what actually triggers constraint changes to be applied to your views.)

That should cause the system to animate the layout changes.